# How are file-extensions/mime-types/icons/default applications associated?

Tags: file-format, mime-type

Is there a way / application to add a file extension / mime-type to the system. What I want to achieve is:

- Have a default program for opening files of this type
- Have a special icon for this filetype
- let `file` output the type of a file of this file in a more specific way.

Is there an way to achieve this?

Comment: @dv3500ea: But how to get this fancy icon in nautilus?

Comment: The link I gave you tells you how to do this at the bottom:


  <https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingMimeTypes#Adding%20an%20Icon>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to:

1. [Add a new MIME type](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingMimeTypes)
2. Associate that MIME type with a program (see [`man xdg-mime`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/xdg-mime.1.html) for more details):

   ```
   xdg-mime default APPLICATION MIMETYPE(S)
   ```