# File association to unlisted application

Tags: gnome, nautilus, mime-type

While browsing files in nautilus, I want to open a tex file with [Kile](https://kile.sourceforge.io/). But, when I get to a dialog similar to the screenshot below, I do not see Kile. Yet, I see it in the "Open With" menu.

How do I fix this?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This question is also useful for any association of a filetype with any application. I recommend using the second method listed in the answer (editing mimeapps.list).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In GNOME3 when apps that show on the right click *Open With Other Application* context menu but not on the right click *Properties* menu do so because the `Exec=` line in the apps `.desktop` doesn't end with a %letter

That's the case with Kile. The 2 most likely letters would be **f** or **U**, I'd try U first.

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/kde4/kile.desktop
```

Make the Exec= line look like this

```
Exec=kile %U
```

Should then show (do a log out/in if needed)

Copied from [my answer here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11480074).

#### Alternate method

An alternate method, (to set as default),  on a per user basis would be to edit `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`

In the `[Default Applications]` section you'd look for this line for plain text, `text/plain=` and this line for LaTex files, `text/x-tex=`

You'd edit either or both to set Kile as default as such

```
text/plain=kile.desktop
text/x-tex=kile.desktop
```

Comment: Thanks - worked. By the way, Why do I see an "edit" button above? Strange for me to be able to edit your answer.

Comment: @vishvAs see http://askubuntu.com/faq#editing

Comment: Sorta new here - I gather you can edit other's answers to improve or correct things

Comment: To set an app as default using CLI check [this answer using `xdg-mime`](https://askubuntu.com/a/4365/349837)  ([here for protocols](https://askubuntu.com/a/1023143/349837)).