# How to add MATLAB to list of applications for Nautlius file type association

Tags: 16.04, nautilus

16.04 Nautilus:  What are the steps to add MATLAB to the list of programs?  The goal is to associate the .mlx file with MATLAB

[image]

Update: `sudo subl /usr/share/applications/matlab.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Icon=/usr/share/icons/matlab.png
Name=MATLAB R2018a
Comment=Start MATLAB - The Language of Technical Computing
Exec=matlab -desktop -useStartupFolderPref 
Exec=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin/matlab -desktop
Categories=Development;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File association to unlisted application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82652/file-association-to-unlisted-application)