# How to change "Foxitreader Document" to normal PDF format?

Tags: pdf, foxitreader

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS version.Few days ago I have installed FoxitReader through terminal but due to some reasons I have uninstalled it but now when I download PDF file from internet it default shows **"FoxitReader Document"** type instead of **"PDF document"** and since I have uninstalled FoxitReader, I can't open such files with **Okular or Document Viewer** so can anyone please help me??

I want to change all files to PDF document files and I don't want to install FoxitReader again.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File association to unlisted application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82652/file-association-to-unlisted-application)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by deleting `~/.local/share/mime/application/pdf.xml`