# Files starting with a comment have the wrong mime type

Tags: default-programs, file-format, mime-type

In Ubuntu 14.04 I have a directory with a set of LESS files, all with the `.less` extension. All but three of the files show a mime type of `plain text document (text/plain)` under Properties > Basic. The other three are reported as `C source code (text/x-csrc)` which means they have a different icon and more annoyingly, get opened with a different default application.

I narrowed the problem down to the contents of the files. It seems any files that start with either a CSS comment block (`/* Comment */`) or a LESS inline comment (`// Comment`) have a mime type of `text/x-csrc`.

I've tried editing the `/etc/mime.types` file to make the system aware of the extension. First I added less as an extension of `text/css`:

`text/css                   css less`

Then I ran `sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime` on the command line but it didn't work, the files still had the wrong mime type so I tried adding it as an extension of `text/plain` in the same way but again, nothing. So I tried adding a new mime type:

`text/less                  less`

I ran the `update-mime-database` command again but still no luck.

How can I get Ubuntu to handle the files based on their extension instead of their contents?

Comment: See if this helps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4361/how-are-file-extensions-mime-types-icons-default-applications-asssociated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the following as e.g. `less.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
  <mime-type type="text/x-less">
    <comment>LESS file</comment>
    <glob pattern="*.less"/>
  </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

Then open a Terminal and run

```
xdg-mime install --novendor less.xml
```

Now all files with the extension `.less` should have the MIME type `text/x-less`.

See [Shared MIME-info Database](http://standards.freedesktop.org/shared-mime-info-spec/latest/) if you want to learn more about how MIME types are defined.