# Ubuntu think my text file is "C source code" file

Tags: nautilus, files, mime-type

When I create a file without file extension and put some text like this in it:

```
//this file is just a simple text file
and you are reading it
```

Ubuntu think it's C source code file and change the icon to the C file. When I right click on the file and click properties, It shows:

```
type: C source code (text/x-csrc)
```

I've noticed every time I start a text file content with `//` Ubuntu think it's not a text file anymore.

[image: Nautilus simple text file as C source code file]

When I run `file` command on the terminal it shows:

```
textfile: ASCII text
```

This problem can fix by adding `.txt` file extension to the filename but I don't want to use `.txt` on the file extension.

There is another thing. When I hit enter and then put `//` in the text file it thinks it's a text file and it's not a C source code file.

[image: Nautilus simple text file]

How can I fix it?

Comment: What is wrong with that? The system tried to guess what type pf a text file was that. The guess was maybe wrong, but it does not affect anything.

Comment: @Pilot6 I know it doesn't affect anything but I have many text files with that format. Every time I see them in Nautilus I must open them to see if they are actuality C file or Not :(

Comment: Possibly related: [Files starting with a comment have the wrong mime type](http://askubuntu.com/questions/639640/files-starting-with-a-comment-have-the-wrong-mime-type). It looks like you can trace this (or similar) behavior right down to the freedesktop [shared-mime-database](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=47376)

Comment: @steeldriver It seems the first link is a little bit different but the second link is the same. It seems I must open and edit every text file I have.

Comment: @ICE How come you don't want to use the `.txt` extension? That makes more sense to me than editing all your files and removing the `//`

Comment: @andy Because I renamed all of my .txt files before. I think the best solution is what you are saying. using .txt extension. Wrong guess is more than `//`. even if I start a text file wit `if` Ubuntu changes the icon to the audio file!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C (and many programming languages) we use "//" to inform compiler to ignore lines starting with that.

I tested myself and made a document like you, and it's treated like c source file too. I even made a document with "/* */" comments, which is also treated as c source file.

These are common for c so you shouldn't be surprised system believes it's source file.

Solution: don't start text files like that I guess.

Comment: I think that's clearly a bug that should be reported in Launchpad. It's insane to assume C if "//" is found. Why not C++? Or JavaScript?

Comment: Maybe it's first language to pass "initial syntax check" while checking the file, who knows? It's a bit funny, but I agree. It' a bug.