# What package to install to play midi files in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, video-player, midi, source-packages

The (ex-totem?) Video player proposes the installation of `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad`, but after installation there is no playback, nothing. When I try to open the .midi file again, the Video player comes up with the installation again and again. So I guess, this is not the right package.

UPDATE: Rythmbox isn't configured to play .midi files either.

[image]

Comment: See [Arch's MIDI doc](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MIDI#Software) and [SoftwareSynthesisHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Midi/SoftwareSynthesisHowTo).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The gstreamer method of playing MIDI is to use the sound card's sequencer to do so. However, many sound cards do not necessarily have an instrument for playing MIDI, these days. Instead, you will need to install a software sequencer, such as `timidity` to play the files.

Answer (score 31):

Open the terminal and enter:

```
sudo apt install timidity timidity-interfaces-extra
```

Enter your password, another prompt may appear type, `Y` and hit enter.

Go to your menu, you should now have an application called *TiMidity++*  launch it. In terminal would be `timidity mymusic.mid`.

In TiMidity++ go to *File > load* and redirect it the location of your midi file, select the file, then `okay` then `play`

Comment: Does anyone know how to associate .mid file to play using timidity?

Comment: Not necessary to install the `timidity-interfaces-extra` - it's quite spooky. Can use `timidity` directly from the terminal.

Comment: @SoichiHayashi check [how to associate any MIME type](https://askubuntu.com/a/4365/349837) with a default program. Then you can test from CLI with `xdg-open filename.mid`.

Comment: under 18.04, timidity works with errors `No instrument mapped to tone bank 0, program 78 - this instrument will not be heard` and it plays nothing where numerous other players (e.g. vlc) play tunes, and its ++ gui version crashes on these errors

Answer (score 31):

VLC media player can do that for you given that the plugin for midi is installed.

```
sudo apt install vlc vlc-plugin-fluidsynth
```

After that you can play your midi library with VLC without installing timidity.

Comment: Note, however, that `vlc-plugin-fluidsynth` uses more disk space than `timidity timidity-interfaces-extra` (119 vs. 35.8MB).

Comment: Worked for me with Ubuntu 20.04 too

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 23.10 as well

Answer (score 8):

I needed proper sound fonts.

```
sudo apt install fluid-soundfont-gm fluid-soundfont-gs
```

Comment: VLC complains about missing sound font file. I installed what you wrote but how to setup sound font file path in VLC? The settings are in Input/Codecs>Audio Codecs>FluidSynth

Comment: ok found it with `dpkg-query -L fluid-soundfont-gm` and `dpkg-query -L fluid-soundfont-gs`!

Comment: I installed fonts and configured VLC but I still can't play midi files. I get error in the console: `fluidsynth decoder error: cannot load sound fonts file /usr/share/sounds/sf2/FluidR3_GS.sf2` or `fluidsynth decoder error: cannot load sound fonts file /usr/share/sounds/sf2/FluidR3_GM.sf2`

Answer (score 0):

There is also a Firefox plugin now: [MIDI Player](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/midi-player/).

If all you need is playing the occasional MIDI that comes up on web pages like on Wikipedia, this may be the simplest solution.