# how to install gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad? WONT INSTALL

Tags: sound, software-installation, plugins

hello AskUbuntu Ive been having trouble for a few days with AUDIO.Mid files for a few games i play like fallout 3 where i need to play AUDIO.mid files

what happens is when i try to play mid files it says needs gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad i click install nothing happens.

i tried searching the plug in on https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad/ but it says package is virtual.

Ive tried googling for a deb but no such deb exists.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

UBUNTU 16.04 XENIAL

Comment: which ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: @Anwar Ubuntu 16.04 XENIAL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What package to install to play midi files in Ubuntu 16.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/771353/what-package-to-install-to-play-midi-files-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: @Anwar its not a dupe i need the plugin to load it while playing games if i try to load the game without the plugin = INSTANT CRASH tehre are ways to play midi but not on the fly without the plugin :(

Comment: are  you using Wine to run the game?

Comment: @anwar Yes i have wine but no one helped me so i figured it out myself

Comment: Noob, you had to give that info in your question

Answer (score -2):

I found a package installer for this issue:

http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/multimedia/gst10-plugins-base.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: That's not an Ubuntu package or package installer, it's a source code tarball. Also, you linked to `gst-plugins-base`, not `gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad` (the "bad" plugins are not included in the "base" plugin package). It's different software.